# Flutter - How to pass user data to all views

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, pass-data

I'm new to the flutter world and mobile app development and struggling with how I should pass user data throughout my app.

I've tried several things, but none seem great and I'm sure there are best practice patterns I should be following.

Because it makes examples easier, I'm using firebase for authentication.
I currently have a separate route for logging in. Once I'm logged in I want the User model in most views for checking permissions on what to show, displaying user info in the drawer, etc...

Firebase has an `await firebaseAuth.currentUser();` Is it best practice to call this everywhere you might need the user? and if so, where is the best spot to place this call?

The [flutter codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/) shows a great example of authenticating users before allowing writes. However, if the page needs to check auth to determine what to build, the async call can't go in the `build` method.

### initState

One method I've tried is to override initState and kick off the call to get the user. When the future completes I call `setState` and update the user.

```
    FirebaseUser user;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _getUserDetail();
    }

  Future<Null> _getUserDetail() async {
    User currentUser = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    setState(() => user = currentUser);
  }
```

This works decent but seems like a lot of ceremony for each widget that needs it. There is also a flash when the screen loads without the user and then gets updated with the user upon the future's completion.

### Pass the user through the constructor

This works too but is a lot of boilerplate to pass the user through all routes, views, and states that might need to access them. Also, we can't just do `popAndPushNamed` when transitioning routes because we can't pass a variable to it. We have to change routes similar to this:

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => new MyPage(user),
));
```

### Inherited Widgets

https://medium.com/@mehmetf_71205/inheriting-widgets-b7ac56dbbeb1

This article showed a nice pattern for using `InheritedWidget`.  When I place the inherited widget at the MaterialApp level, the children aren't updating when the auth state changed (I'm sure I'm doing it wrong)

```
  FirebaseUser user;

  Future<Null> didChangeDependency() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    User currentUser = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    setState(() => user = currentUser);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new UserContext(
      user,
      child: new MaterialApp(
        title: 'TC Stream',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: new LoginView(title: 'TC Stream Login', analytics: analytics),
        routes: routes,
      ),
    );
  }
```

### FutureBuilder

FutureBuilder also seems like a decent option but seems to be a lot of work for each route. In the partial example below, `_authenticateUser()` is getting the user and setting state upon completion.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
      future: _authenticateUser(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return _buildProgressIndicator();
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return _buildPage();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I'd appreciate any advice on best practice patterns or links to resources to use for examples.

Comment: There are lot's different way. But InheritedWidget is interesting feature of Flutter for data propagation. You can find an example of InheritedWidget here https://gitlab.com/brianegan/scoped_model . Also you can consider to use Redux https://pub.dartlang.org/search?q=redux

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd recommend investigating inherited widgets further; the code below shows how to use them with asynchronously updating data:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Inherited Widgets Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('Inherited Widget Example'),
          ),
          body: new NamePage())));
}

// Inherited widget for managing a name
class NameInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  const NameInheritedWidget({
    Key key,
    this.name,
    Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final String name;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(NameInheritedWidget old) {
    print('In updateShouldNotify');
    return name != old.name;
  }

  static NameInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) {
    // You could also just directly return the name here
    // as there's only one field
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(NameInheritedWidget);
  }
}

// Stateful widget for managing name data
class NamePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NamePageState createState() => new _NamePageState();
}

// State for managing fetching name data over HTTP
class _NamePageState extends State<NamePage> {
  String name = 'Placeholder';

  // Fetch a name asynchonously over HTTP
  _get() async {
    var res = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    var name = json.decode(res.body)[0]['name'];
    setState(() => this.name = name); 
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _get();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new NameInheritedWidget(
      name: name,
      child: const IntermediateWidget()
    );
  }
}

// Intermediate widget to show how inherited widgets
// can propagate changes down the widget tree
class IntermediateWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  // Using a const constructor makes the widget cacheable
  const IntermediateWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new Padding(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: const NameWidget()));
  }
}

class NameWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NameWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final inheritedWidget = NameInheritedWidget.of(context);
    return new Text(
      inheritedWidget.name,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks for the example!  My latest attempts have been to wrap the `Scaffold` in an `InheritedWidget` so the information is available in the `drawer`, `appBar`, and the `body`. I've been playing with the `FutureBuilder` in conjunction with the inherited widgets for loading the content.

Comment: Have you tried using onAuthStateChanges with a StreamBuilder?

Comment: I stuck with a problem with InheritedWidget – it can't be used from `initState()`. Moving it to `didChangeDependencies()` helps, but then it gets called multiple times, even if the widget is no longer active. In my case, InheritedWidget holds API wrapper, so that solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to use Services with Locator, using [Flutter get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it).

Create a UserService with a cached data if you like:

```
class UserService {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  final String _collectionName = 'users';
  CollectionReference _ref;

  User _cachedUser; //<----- Cached Here

  UserService() {
    this._ref = _db.collection(_collectionName);
  }

  User getCachedUser() {
    return _cachedUser;
  }

  Future<User> getUser(String id) async {
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await _ref.document(id).get();

    if (!doc.exists) {
      log("UserService.getUser(): Empty companyID ($id)");
      return null;
    }

    _cachedUser = User.fromDocument(doc.data, doc.documentID);
    return _cachedUser;
  }
}
```

Then create create a Locator

```
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

void setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => new UserService());
}
```

And instantiate in main()

```
void main() {
  setupLocator();
  new Routes();
}
```

That's it! You can call your Service + cachedData everywhere using:

```
.....
UserService _userService = locator<UserService>();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _user = _userService.getCachedUser();
}
```

Comment: how to user this approch when the user reopen the app the _cachedUser will be destroy?

Answer (score 1):

I crashed into another problem because of this problem [you can check it out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964709/how-to-properly-implement-logout-with-firebase-on-flutter)
So the solution I came up with is a bit untidy,I created a separate Instance dart page and imported it to every page.

```
 GoogleSignInAccount Guser = googleSignIn.currentUser;
 FirebaseUser Fuser;
```

I stored the user there on login and checked on every StateWidget if it was null

```
  Future<Null> _ensureLoggedIn() async {

if (Guser == null) Guser = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
if (Fuser == null) {
  await googleSignIn.signIn();
  analytics.logLogin();
}
if (await auth.currentUser() == null) {
  GoogleSignInAuthentication credentials =
  await googleSignIn.currentUser.authentication;
  await auth.signInWithGoogle(
    idToken: credentials.idToken,
    accessToken: credentials.accessToken,
  );
}
```

This is my old code I did cleaned it up on my current app but I don't have that code now in handy. Just check out for null user and log it in again

I did it for most of the Firebase instances too because I have more than 3 pages on my app and Inherited Widgets was just too much work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GetX package to check whether or not the user is logged in, get user data and have it accessible throughout your app

Comment: how can we do that?

Answer (score -2):

For my lazy mathod,
i just create new file like **userdata.dart** and then put any variable on it for example like **dynamic Profile = null**

inside **userdata.dart**

```
//only put this or anything u want.
dynamic Profile = null;
```

at **startingpage.dart**

```
//import that file
import '../userdata.dart';

class startingpage extends ...{
...
//set data to store..
   Profile = 'user profile';
...
}
```

to use the data just declare and use in
**anotherpage.dart**

```
//import that file
import '../userdata.dart';

class anotherpage extends...{
...
}

class .. State ...{
...
//set the data to variable
   dynamic userdata = Profile;
   print('this is my lazy pass data' + userdata.toString());
...
}
```

Comment: you can give share preference example in it.