# How to properly implement Logout with firebase on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

It sounds stupid but I cant really properly logout of my app and that is because I use multiple FirebaseAnimatedList and route on my MaterialApp

```
routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
    '/StartAppPage':(BuildContext context)=>new StartAppPage(),
    '/LoginPage':(BuildContext context)=> new LoginPage(),
    '/HomePage':(BuildContext context)=> new HomePage)
  },
```

So the app checks for use and routes to HomePage or Login based on is there is a user or not.

My Home page has a FirebaseAnimatedList and
on my Home page there is a Logout button that  do this

```
await googleSignIn.signOut();
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
await FirebaseDatabase.instance.goOffline();
return Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/StartApp');
```

to HomePage and logout the user.

But when the other user login again the List shows data of the old user and the list is usable messing my Database

How can I properly implement this and the setPersistance is off or on makes no difference

Solution: Keep a single instance of your firebase user through the app. I recommend a global variable

Comment: Show your method that you use to log the user out

Comment: It also may be an issue related to the way you are communicating data from your database

Comment: I don't get you, how exactly ?

Comment: I mean it is either you are not properly signing the user out or you are not viewing the data in the correct way (based on current user)

Comment: That makes more sense, I can log in and log out with right users, the query I am using requires my current user details to execute.Its currently awaiting a user to be there to show the list and the user is set on every page.

Comment: This was bugging me so much thanks

Comment: @Prime Please do not replace the body of your question with an answer. Post the answer as an answer.

Comment: My implementation turnout to be completely unrelated to the main question. I'll add on the answer

Answer (score 0):

After signing out, what you can consider doing here is check on the current screen if the user is authenticated or not. If the user is still logged-in, display the data. If not, then navigate to a Login screen.

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .idTokenChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      debugPrint('User is currently signed out!');
      // TODO: navigate to Login screen?
    } else {
      debugPrint('User is signed in!');
      // TODO: display data
    }
  });
```