# How to get a context for Navigator in Widget initState()?

Tags: flutter

I want my app to work offline without a user set, and asking for a login when connectivity is back

en excerpt of the code I'm trying:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) =>
        checkConnectivity().then((isOnline) {
          if (isOnline && MyApp.store.state.user == null)
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
              );
        }));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(          
      routes: {
...
```

but all I can get is this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
```

I tried to wrap my `Navigator` call inside a `Future.delayed` as described [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19330#issuecomment-404694788) but I got the same error

Comment: where have you declare `MaterialApp` ?

Comment: Instead of subscribing to the stream in your initState, use a StreamBuilder widget. StreamBuilder take a stream, and a builder method. The builder method will run when the stream emits a new event and you can show different views based on the latest value from the stream.

Comment: @anmol.majhail just below, i edited the code in the answer

Comment: @Doc You need to define - `MaterialApp` one level above - `MyApp` - so that `Navigator.of` can work.  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54865428/10269042