# how can i fix : Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: flutter

I´m new in flutter and i´m trying to create a navigation to another page called Registro();

I'm trying with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427825/how-to-fix-navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a)that i found in a post here in stackoverflow.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(home: Login());
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String _title = 'Sample App';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          elevation: 3,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text('¿No tienes una cuenta?'),
              TextButton(
                child: const Text(
                  'Registrate',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Registro()),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also i tried this solution -> and doesnt works :c

[Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004451/navigator-operation-requested-with-a-context-that-does-not-include-a-navigator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `Navigator.push(context, yourPageRoute)`, (which does a `Navigator.of(context)`), `context` needs to be able to access a `Navigator` placed above in the widget tree.
Usually, this `Navigator` is the root one that is being built in `MaterialApp`.

I your case you have

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(  // <- The Navigator is inside this widget.
    // ...
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context);
        // ...
      }, 
    ),
  );
}
```

But the `context` you are using comes from the `build` method of `MyApp`, which is not below the `MaterialApp` widget you are using.

So you need to use the context that comes from below the `MaterialApp` in the widget tree.

## How to solve it

You could use a `Builder` widget to be able to access the `context` from its `builder` method:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(  // <- The Navigator is inside this widget.
    // ...
    Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context); // <- Now the context comes from Builder which is below MaterialApp and you should be able to access its Navigator.
            // ...
          }, 
        ),
      },
    ),

  );
}
```