# Flutter.io Navigator errors in appbar

Tags: dart, flutter

I've decided to give flutter a try and stumbled upon the following problem:

In my app I would like to have a button in the AppBar that would take the user to another screen. However whenever I attempt to call Navigator in any of the IconButtons' onPressed handlers, I get the following error:

> Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
>   The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
>   descendant of a Navigator widget.

Here's my **main.dart** (minus the imports):

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var service = new ProjectService();

    return new MaterialApp(
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        ),
        home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text("My App Title"),
              actions: 
              <Widget>[
                new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () =>
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/projects/add")) //<-- Here's where I get the exception
              ],
              elevation: 0.0),
          body: new Center(child: new ProjectList(projects: service.toList())), //<-- Exactly the same code runs fine here
          drawer: new AppDrawer(),
        ),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/projects/add': (BuildContext context) => new ProjectAddScreen(),
          '/projects/test': (BuildContext context) => new ProjectAddScreen(),
          '/settings': (BuildContext context) => new AppSettingsScreen(),
          '/about': (BuildContext context) => new AboutScreen()
        });
  }
}
```

This is the only place where the app instance is constructed and `AppBar` is the standard `AppBar` that comes bundled with the flutter/material package.

My `flutter doctor` output if that's of any relevance

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v0.2.5-pre.41, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.309], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown. // I use the SDK manager from Visual Studio
[!] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version. //I use the SDK manager from Visual Studio so I have no need in Android Studio
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.21.1)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)
```

Comment: @rémi-rousselet, thanks for pointing this one out. Conceptually, my question indeed seems like it's a duplicate of that thread, however the code posted there is different. Moreover none of the official guides on flutter that I've seen shows instantiating a `Scaffold` or an `AppBar` via a `Builder` so I did not pay enough attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

Though as Rémi pointed out in his comment to this question (sorry, I don't know how to properly mention his user), this turns out to be a duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373774/inheritedwidget-with-scaffold-as-child-doesnt-seem-to-be-working). But because I find the code provided there a bit out of context I think it's worth to mention how I applied the solution provided there in my particular use-case.

I did some debugging and found out that when I'm inside the `onPressed` handler of the `IconButton`, the context there is not that of the `IconButton` or the `AppBar`. It is that of the `MaterialApp`. If you ask me it is both logical and weird at the same time, especially if you take into consideration that putting the same code inside body' center works.

But nevertheless, I opened the Stocks sample app and took a look at how they structured the app and simply followed the pattern they used there.

Here's what I ended up with:

**main.dart**

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return new MyAppState();
  }

}

class MyAppStateextends State<MyApp> {

  ProjectService _projectService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _projectService = new ProjectService();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
       title: "My App",
        theme: new ThemeData.light(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
          '/projects/add': (BuildContext context) => new HomeScreen(_projectService),
          '/': (BuildContext context) => new HomeScreen(_projectService)
        }
    );
  }
}
```

**HomeScreen.dart**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final ProjectService projectService;

  const HomeScreen(this.projectService);

  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => new HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  void handleProjectUpdate() {
    setState(() => {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new ListView(
        children: widget.projectService.all().map<ListTile>((f) {
          return new ListTile(
            title: new Text(f.name),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/projects/add"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```